# Is there a way to capture the screenshot of specific elementID on Android screen in Appium using Selenium (Java)?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to capture the screenshot of only a part of Android screen specific to an element ID. Not the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your specific context, any way to get a screenshot of an image represented in a `<img>` HTML, some times ago I used this code in one of my projects. Hope this could help and could be similar to your situation

```
WebDriver drv2 = new ChromeDriver();
drv2.get("https://www.example.com");
WebElement el = drv2.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='/page.php']"));
File SrcFile = el.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
File DestFile = new File("/your/path/file.png");
Files.copy(SrcFile.toPath(),DestFile.toPath());
```

where the HTML tag was something like

```
<img src="page.php" />
```

Change `//img[@src='/page.php']` with your HTML tags info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am running a Android Application on Emulator. I want to capture the screenshot of a screen element only not the whole screen. Is this possible in Appium

Comment: @Cherry yes. if you’re running it on selenium and it’s a web page , you can capture the screenshot of a specific element represented by its HTML tag just like I wrote above. Otherwise you don’t need selenium to do this but you need to poke around with API of your operating system.